# java retrieve objects from a Set

Tags: java, collections

In Java 5, If i have a Set, and i add two objects to the Set. When I retrieve the objects, will it give me back in the same order as I added?
I am not able to find the answer to this. Does it depend on which Set implementation I use?

Comment: I was going to ask "Why not just use a Queue", and then I saw the word "Set". :) So I assume you want your data structure to maintain the "uniqueness" property? If yes, then as Jon Skeet mentioned, LinkedHashSet is perfect. If you don't care about uniqueness, then a Queue will do just fine.

Comment: It's right in `Set`'s documentation. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it depends on which implementation you use. For example, [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) will preserve insertion order:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set. (An element e is reinserted into a set s if s.add(e) is invoked when s.contains(e) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)

... but [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) won't:

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. This class permits the null element.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator%28%29):

> The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is
>   an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on `Set` implementation. `LinkedHashSet` does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does depend on the implementation you choose. [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) will not guarantee order but [LinedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) will.

Answer (score 0):

JavaDocs is your best friend. It's implementation specific. For example:

```
java.util.Set:

Iterator<E> iterator(); 
Returns an iterator over the elements in this set. The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).
```

and

```
java.util.TreeSet:

public Iterator<E> iterator();
Returns an iterator over the elements in this set in ascending order.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Set` interface itself is for unordered container implementations. But there might be implementations of `Set` that do return the elements in a particular order.

Also see the documentation of [`Set.iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator%28%29):

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this set. The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee)